# how to target click event in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I target the click event so that I can reuse the .js-box in different divs without effecting the other div containers?

```
var box = document.querySelector('.js-box'),
    colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];

box.onclick = function() {
    color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);

    box.className = 'js-box' + ' ' + color;
};
```

I'm quite sure my solution is to do with the correct use of 'this' but i can seem to get my head around it

http://jsfiddle.net/Grundizer/ky1tb3r5/

Comment: use `this.className` instead of `box.className`. Also, yeah, you need to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only selects the first element, not all!

Thats why you need `document.getElementsByClassName`

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('js-box'),
    colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];



for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
{
    boxes[i].onclick = function() {
        color = colors.shift();
        colors.push(color);
        
        this.className = 'js-box' + ' ' + color;
    };
}
```

```css
.js-box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px;
    border:thin grey solid;
    display:block;
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
}
.green {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-box"></div>
<div class="js-box"></div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `querySelectorAll`.